# Dockerized nginx proxy returns 504

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, google-compute-engine

I have a dockerized nginx reverse proxy serving files for my app container. It seams to work fine as if I connect to a folder in my browser using:

```
<my_external_ip>/demofolder
```

Then I get the list of the files and folders in it.

On my local environment when I click on a php file in the browser, then i get the webpage displayed.
On this google compute engine instance, I get a time out error :

```
504 Gateway Time-out
```

If I look at the container log I get the following:

```
nginx.1    | 2017/02/02 15:38:59 [error] 35#35: *15 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) 
while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.162.xxx.xxx, 
server: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, request: "GET /demo/index.php HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://172.17.0.5:80/demo/index.php", host: "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", 
referrer: "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/demo/"
```

Where 172.17.0.5 is the right container internal ip.

ping 172.17.0.5 is successfull.
when I attach to the proxy container I see stdin/out.
when I attach to the app container there is no stdin/out message.

when I run `sudo docker logs <app container id>` I get

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

When I look at my config file I have the external IP as ServerName, which is right.

What do i miss here ?

Comment: NGINX is not receiving a response from the upstream server. Could be a lot of reasons for that. Can you ping from NGINX to the upstream server?

Comment: yes the ping to 172.17.0.5:80 runs successfully

Comment: Instead of a ping, do a `curl http://172.17.0.5:80/demo/index.php` to test the application itself from inside your nginx container. If that fails, test the same curl from the target app container. It may also help to know the version of docker.